# 'Not Responding' when connecting to Socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am connecting to a socket to read incoming data from an ADS-B box.
Everything works fine when data is coming in, but whenever there is no data, I get the 'Not Responding' message appear, which I presume is because of the `while True` statement. My understanding of this is it is because it is waiting for something to happen. I even tried it without a while statement, but the same thing happens.

How can I stop the Not Responding message (along with the mouse hourglass) from appearing please?

Oh yes it is on Win10 with Python 3.8.3

My code is as follows:

```
import socket
    
HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 30003        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
```

Thanks

Comment: That'a not much information to go on. How is the ADS-B box connected to your win10 computer? Why are you connecting to port 30003 on 127.0.0.1? Also what context are you running this program in? Why is there an hourglass appearing?

Comment: Sorry I am a newbie at Python.
The ADS-B box is connected to a USB plug in the PC.
Port 30003 is the port that the software in the ADS-B box sends decoded information to the computer on
What do you mean by what context am I running this program in?
ADS-B box picks up ADS-B signals transmitted by aircraft and contains flight information. It comes with it's own software but the developer passed away and after 10 years his software has finally stopped working, so I am trying to create my own version of it.

Comment: The hourglass is what appears as the mouse cursor whenever the program 'hangs'. Not sure if that is the right term to use. In the top bar of my python app, it says 'Not Responding' but the mouse curser/pointer also changes..not an hourglass, sorry, a circle that 'spins'. I am new to Win10 so thought that was the new equivalent to the hourglass